# translate detect API is giving timeout

Tags: node.js, google-translate

need some help here please...over the last 1-2 weeks, I've been getting regular delays in my translations. (It's been working correctly for months, without timeouts)  I'm getting:

`FetchError: network timeout at: https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/detect`

I'm using node.js framework, and I see several of these per day now, each day.

(please note, I am not seeing any errors on "translate", but just on the "detect")

any help possible?

Answer (score 0):

ok so after looking long and hard, and nobody answering...I decided that I would try something else.  I went to the v3 interface, which allows for detection and translation in the same call, and I avoided the detect interface of v2.  This looks like it is working, as the delays I faced from detect call ( and not translate ) are gone now.  Hope someone else can benefit.